# background-tasks creating of tasks and handling completed tasks

Tags: django, background-task

I am using [django-background-tasks](https://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to read data from an API into my database. A cronjob is starting `python manage.py process_tasks` every 15 minutes and works off the jobs in the queue. The task is looking like:

```
@background(schedule = 900)
def API_2_DB()
    ....
    return None
```

Now for the first question:
So, how do I reliable create the tasks that will be worked off while the page is "not in use"?

Second question: The database is stockpiling completed tasks - I know I can easily delete them with `CompletedTasks.objects.all().delete()` somewhere - but is there no built in automatism for this?

Answer (score 0):

As I needed to look around a lot and Stackoverflow being my major source for django related questions, I thought I shared what I learned in case someone comes looking for the same question here:

After a task was created in the task.py inside an app you can regularly call that task while no user is active calling it from the project `urls.py`:

urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView

urlpatterns = [
    path('home/', RedirectView.as_view(url='/')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('APPName.urls')), 
]

from APPName.tasks import API_2_DB

API_2_DB(repeat=100, repeat_until=None)
```

Comment: While it works, this is a bad place to put this kind of function call. You'll get an enormous amount of tasks queued up or if the visits are super infrequent the `repeat => 10000`. Normally you'd want a cron job at a regular interval to load the jobs just like you have with `process_tasks`, but once you have that you don't need Django Background Tasks.

Comment: indeed you are correct. I ran in exactly this problem and switched to huey because of it. Before that, I had a second worker that cleaned the tasks up for me :(